# How to generate ROC Curve with cross validation using SGD classifier loss=hinge

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

We want to generate ROC cure with corss validation using SGD classifier with loss=hinge but it does not support because ROC curve requires probability. We want to strictly stick with hinge because it has fit our requirement and want to verify trained model accuracy using ROC curve.Please suggest how to generate ROC curve with cross validation using loss=hinge

Comment: You can use a [CalibratedClassifierCV on top of your SGD](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html) to get the probabilities or use [roc_curve](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html) on your actual values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you can use a Decision Function for "loss=hinge" that gives you distance from hyperplane 
here how you can apply

```
svm_clf.fit(Xtrain, Xtarget)
score_roc = svm_clf.decision_function(Ytest)
        fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(Ytarget, score_roc)
        roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
        plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
        plt.plot(fpr, tpr, 'b', label='AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)
        plt.legend(loc='lower right')
        plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
        plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
        plt.show()
```